# What are these weird Doritos picks that Daron Malakian uses?

Tags: picks

[image]

What are these weird triangle picks? I have never seen ones like these before. You can see them on the mic stand.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently these picks are *custom made* Dunlop Tortex .88 and the only way to get these with sharpen tips is from Malakian himself ;).

[More infos.](https://www.reddit.com/r/systemofadown/comments/9qt6vy/what_guitar_pick_does_daron_use/)

Comment: That said, I'm 80% sure I've seen picks in that shape in stores, and a quick Google Image search for "triangular pick" shows that several manufacturers have made some, so if OP is willing to settle for something similarly shaped, he can probably just buy a pack.

Comment: Though, given the ludicrous number of Dunlop pick designs, I'm surprised they don't just make a System of a Down Signature Pick. ;)

Comment: @Taschi I was a bit surprised also, hovewer it has been a long time since I actually bought some picks ;). But did not found this sharp shape on Dunlop's store :/

Answer (score 2):

These are pretty common.  I have several.  His might be custom but you should be able to get these at most stores.  I got mine back in the 80s or 90s.